# Ubuntu 12.04 orange hex name (it's not #dd4814)

Tags: 12.04, default, colors

Change to bright blue and now wanna change back to default with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-color-scheme 'selected_bg_color:HEXNAME;'
```

I used this site to get some names: http://www.2createawebsite.com/build/hex-colors.html

but what is the default hex?

Thanks!

Comment: so you say that this isn't #dd4814? http://design.canonical.com/2011/07/ubuntu-orange-is-dd4814/

Comment: no as you can see here: http://i50.tinypic.com/2ij430p.png

Comment: You know that you can take a screenshon and use the color picket to retrieve the name?

Comment: i cant do that, if do-i already have another color. could you please chack it for me?

Comment: http://www.colorhexa.com/dd4814 I think it's that color.

Comment: i also tought it is, but as you can see here: http://i50.tinypic.com/2ij430p.png it's different (too dark).           can you look in your setting files to the color?

Comment: is it #f07746? i almost sure. is that the default color?

Comment: If cannonical says it's #dd4814, then it's that color. Leave it.

Comment: this is the color for the logo, there's a different. here i gave you the picture where you can see how this color look in the system.

Answer (score 3):

The default orange used in Ubuntu products and throughout the Ubuntu software - officially named Ubuntu Orange is:

### [#dd4814](http://design.canonical.com/2011/07/ubuntu-orange-is-dd4814/)

This is confirmed and **officially** stated [here](http://design.canonical.com/2011/07/ubuntu-orange-is-dd4814/). There is no questions about it, `#dd4814` is Ubuntu Orange!

I even took the liberty to test this in Gimp. I used Libre Office Writer and wrote the following below in the preset colour called 'Ubuntu Orange'. I then went into Gimp and used the colour-grab tool. Sure enough, the link is true and any doubts can be put to rest!

[image: ubuntu orage]

Answer (score 1):

OP is correct -- while the Ubuntu orange IS #dd4814, the **selected_bg_color** that OP is specifically looking for is NOT Ubuntu orange. It is **#f07746**. You can find this by reading the contents of /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini. Hope this helps!

(Apologies if this topic is too old to answer or whatnot, but I had this exact same question today and was able to find the answer on another site)